# image processing package using c++ in geany IDE for fedora 27

Tags: opencv

i have already surf a lot to include opencv in geany. i couldn't find a right way.anyone guide me a way to include opencv for image processing using c++ in geany. 
how do use opencv or other image processing packages in geany IDE for fedora 27 platform?